# How use Django to create a search bar on the home page, then redirect to search results?

Tags: django

I have a search bar on my jobs_board.html page which works well. But I want to add this search bar to my home page so it performs the same search and redirects to the jobs_board.html page to display the results. Any suggestions on how I can add this the home.html and it's view.py

Thanks in advance.

jobs/views.py

```
def get_jobs_queryset(query=None):
    queryset = []
    queries = query.split(" ")
    for q in queries:
        posts = JobsPost.objects.filter(
            Q(title__contains=q)|
            Q(body__icontains=q)
            ).distinct()
        for post in posts:
            queryset.append(post)



def board_jobs_view(request):

    context = {}

    query = ""
    if request.GET:
        query = request.GET['q']
        context['query'] = str(query)

    jobs_posts = sorted(get_jobs_queryset(query), key=attrgetter('date_updated'), reverse=True)
    context['jobs_posts'] = jobs_posts

    return render(request, "jobs/jobs_board.html", context)
```

jobs_board.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="center">
            <h1 class="display-4">
            <form method="get">
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg"  type="text" name="q" id="id_q" placeholder="Search Jobs">
            </h1>
    </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("id_q").value = "{{query}}"
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify the path of the search view as `action="…"` attribute in the `<form>` tag:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'board_job_view' %}">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg"  type="text" name="q" id="id_q" placeholder="Search Jobs">
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Here `board_job_view` is the *name* of the view, so the path should look somethin like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path(… views.board_jobs_view, name='board_jobs_view')
    # …,
]
```